# How to use CPUID instruction to get x86 CPU features correctly?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, x86-64, cpuid

I want to write a small program to get the features of `x86`CPUs. After referring [CPUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) document, I find there are `2` sections:

(1) [EAX=1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits):

```
......
As of January 2011, the standard Intel feature flags are as follows: 
......
```

(2) [EAX=80000001h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D80000001h:_Extended_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits):

```
......
AMD feature flags are as follows:
......
```

So it means if CPU vendor is `GenuineIntel`, I should use `EAX=1` while if it is `AuthenticAMD`, I should use `EAX=80000001h` to execute `CPUID` instruction. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What exactly do you want to detect?  If it's something vendor-neutral like SSSE3, then you should execute CPUID with the inputs specified by the feature you're trying to detect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring [AMD CPUID](https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/25481.pdf) and [Intel CPUID](https://www.microbe.cz/docs/CPUID.pdf) documents, I can learn their flags are different for `EAX 1 CPUID` instruction, so need to differentiate them.